# OpenVPN: How to change VPN connections

Tags: openvpn

I want to change my VPN connections to different servers without having to restart my computer. I currently use the GUI connection icon in 16.10 to do my initial connections and input setting for additional connections. But once I have selected a VPN connection I cannot seem to change to a different VPN connection until I restart my computer. Sometimes I can disconnect and run without the VPN and even reconnect to the original VPN connection, but selecting another connection may say that it is connected, but I have no internet traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you head over to [vpnbook website](http://vpnbook.com) and download all the  certificate bundles they offer in the **openvpn** section and use the following command whenever you want to connect to any of the downloaded bundles `openvpn --config (name of bundle).ovpn`. When prompted to enter username and password use the details given on the website.